# Any drawback to lots of creating and renaming tables at InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, innodb, insert

I'm trying to optimize an important cronjob for my program, and what it basically does is generate a long list of user ids with their score points. I have a table called user_ranks and it will bulk insert all of that data into that table. Normally that went fine, but it is taking a longer and longer time, which now is giving huge problems to my website. 
The bulk insert query takes about 5 seconds, which is too much. It is blocking other queries to that table. (I'm using row level locking but it locks the whole table)

Now what my idea to optimize this is, is to do the bulk inserting in another table, say user_ranks_new and then after the insert is done, rename the `user_ranks` table to `user_ranks_old` and `user_ranks_new` to `user_ranks` and afterwards dropping the old table.

This is obviously a lot faster than blocking the important table (`user_ranks`) for about 5 seconds. 
This cronjob runs every 10 minutes, so I want it optimized a lot.

**Are there any drawbacks to creating lots of tables, renaming them, and dropping them? Does the ibdata files gets a lot bigger, or any other?**

p.s. I'm aware of settings like shown on this page (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html), but they didn't really help significantly.

Comment: I don't know if MySQL has this or not, but if you don't have an atomic "exchange"-type operation to do the switch you're dead - queries will randomly fail rather than taking a bit more time. (I'm not sure there are RDBMSs that provide an atomic and non-blocking "exchange"-type thing. Sounds entirely non-trivial wrt global database consistency - but I could be wrong there.)

Comment: QUESTIONS : 1) What is the output for `SELECT data_length, index_length, (data_length+index_length) tblsize FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB';`? 2) How much RAM on the DB Server? 3) What is `SELECT version();`? 4) Do you have `innodb_file_per_table` enabled? 5) Any MyISAM in this mix? 6) Is this a bar metal serve or a VM? 7) How many rows are you loading into `user_ranks`? 8) How many CPU/Cores ?

Comment: 1) hmm, a lot of rows are there, do you want to see them all?
2) 10GB RAM
3) version: 5.5.25a
4) Yes, enabled
5) Yes, but not many tables.. about 3%
6) Virtual machine, it's a VPS. 
7) about 300.000
8) 6 processors

Comment: Mat, Thanks for your reply too, by the way, I have no clue if that exists and it's an important point.

And forgot to mention @RolandoMySQLDBA